# Unable to extract country name 'UK' from text using geograpy

Tags: python, geograpy

I am trying to extract the UK as a country name from text file using geograpy, but It's returning an empty list. My code is:

```
import geograpy
text = 'I am from the UK'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)

print (places.countries)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Is there a way get ['UK'] as an output? Thank you.

Comment: Are all the other fields empty, like `places.other`? Does `text = 'I am from the United Kingdom'` do anything different?

Comment: Yes, it identifies correctly `['United Kingdom']` with `places.countries` with the `text = 'I am from the United Kingdom'`. The `places.other` field contains `['UK']` with the original text. I am not sure if this should make sense, though - why is the UK not identified as a country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`places.other`](https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3#basic-usage):

> lists everything that wasn't clearly a country, region or city.

```
import geograpy

text = 'I am from the UK'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)
print(places.other)
```

**Output:**

```
['UK']
```

Comment: Great, thank you, it works! But I am not sure why the 'UK' doesn't appear under `places.countries` - is there a reason for it and is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Not sure, `USA` seems to also be put in other but interestingly `NZ` seems to be placed under regions, and `New Zealand` placed under countries at the same time. Maybe it is just how unambiguous it is or something